# Craft 3 automatic update

Tags: craft3, updates, auto-updates

Does anyone think there will be an automatic update from 2-3? Or as the file structure is different do you think it'll be unlikely?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are no plans for an automatic update from Craft 2 to Craft 3. I'd suggest following the instructions from the docs to perform the update manually: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html

Comment: Jalen gave a soft "no", but let me back that up with a hard "no". There are way too many things that changed, including giant changes to the file architecture. There is a near 0% chance that an automatic update between C2 -> C3 will ever be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to happen. There is a multitude of reasons, but the biggest one would be breaking changes, including templates. Allowing an auto-update that would likely break the site would be reckless.